# Questions About Using Amazon Web Services (AWS) For Remote Development

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

We are a very small mobile company (building an application for the iphone) and we are currently considering hosting services. We are currently leaning towards Amazon's hosting/web services. Accordingly, I have some questions:

1) Can I create an admin account on AWS and assign user accounts to developers that should have access to most (but not all) features.

2) Do we need to learn / use AWS APIs in the development of our product? I don't like the 
idea of having to create hooks into a hosting service.

3) It looks like the pricing for AWS scales with usage. So, since we are in development and have only developers accessing the server right now, am I right that the cost will be quite low if anything?

4) How does AWS do version management? We have several developers scattered throughout the country. Each will need to checkout the the recent build from the server for development 
on his local box. Basically, something like SVN. Is this possible?

5) I am guessing we need something like a dev, svn, and production server? Is this right? If so, how do I set this up and find out the associated costs?

6) We are considering a few database options, among them NoSQL and Neo4j - will we be able to do this using AWS? The server language will be Java.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, kind of. There is Identity and Access Management offered by AWS, but it's not the easiest solution to use. Having said that, it can allow you to lock down some of the access activities on an account so that you have some control over your users. I would say that AWS is still very much a single-user environment for server administrators.
2. You could get away using only the management console. Your use of scripting may only be required if you want to run batch or periodic activities (eg. take a snapshot of all machines at 2am every night).
3. Costs for EC2 are low, especially for the Micro machine sizes. But keep in mind that the idea of cloud computing is the availability of on-demand resources for short term use. If you run dev machines needlessly over night then you will still be paying! And if someone launches an Extra Large machine (or 30 machine instances) then you will suddenly find yourself with bigger bills than expected.
4. (5. and 6. as well) Amazon EC2 is really about issuing you the boxes. What you do thereafter is fully up to you. You can create snapshots daily of your machines, you can deploy SVN and noSQL etc. etc.

I've been seriously into EC2 for a while now, and lots of companies are starting to look at the idea you propose. There are benefits to giving staff on-demand compute power, without having to manage any infrastructure in-house. But I will re-iterate my first point that EC2 is very much a single-user, server administration environment, which doesn't lend itself to being used as a dev playground without additional tools. (Or at least it becomes a challenging task if you have several devs spread around in your company).

I own a business that helps companies use EC2 for dev/lab/playground type of environments. I won't directly flog it here, but will show a quick demo we just put on DropBox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16347737/RequestEC2Machines.html  Feel free to request a machine to see how adding process to EC2 can help meet your goals.

Answer (score 1):

I run/develop a website using Amazon EC2 & SimpleDB and I have some comments for you on your questions

Hi.

We are a very small mobile company (building an application for the iphone) and we are currently considering hosting services. We are currently leaning towards Amazon's hosting/web services. Accordingly, I have some questions:

> 1) Can I create an admin account on
>   AWS and assign user accounts to
>   developers that should have access to
>   most (but not all) features.

In my experience, there doesn't seem to be a direct correspondence between Amazon users and users on a single instance. An instance's root account is connected to the amazon account indirectly through a key pair. Although, I must say that I haven't explored this question in detail.

> 2) Do we need to learn / use AWS APIs in the development of our product? I don't like the > idea of having to create hooks into a hosting service.

I manage everything through their web console and Eclipse IDE plugins. I've never had to touch the API yet for development and deployment.

> 3) It looks like the pricing for AWS scales with usage. So, since we are in
>   development and have only developers accessing the server right now, am
>   I right that the cost will be quite low if anything?

Micro instances cost the lowest and the cost is pretty good if you're just starting an instance for a couple of hours and then stopping it. I never think twice about starting a micro instance to try out something new

> 4) How does AWS do version management? We have several developers
>   scattered throughout the country. Each will need to checkout the the recent
>   build from the server for development on his local box. Basically, something like SVN.
>   Is this possible?
>   I haven't seen this feature being offered directly by Amazon. You can of course keep an instance always on for your repository with backups
>
> 5) I am guessing we need something like a dev, svn, and production server?
>   Is this right? If so, how do I set this up and find out the associated costs?

EC Pricing - http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Amazon Simple Monthly Calculator - http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

> 6) We are considering a few database options, among them NoSQL and Neo4j -
>   will we be able to do this using AWS? The server language will be Java.

Amazon instances can be what you want them to be, hence you can either use a pre-configured ami to launch an instance or start off with a bare bones Ubuntu Server or Windows Server e.g. and build a system with what you want. You can then save the snapshot of that system to launch more in the future or to re-launch if your instance crashes

Comment: Danish, Thanks for the detailed response. I have some follow-up to #1 and #4. #1: maybe I am not understanding the set-up but are you saying that developers have to log in with the same credentials you used to set up the account (and have access to all your payment information)? #2: So, Amazon allows developers to check out (and update) nightly builds to their local environments? How do you currently do version management for your company?

Comment: No Problem! Please remember, I'm not an expert, just sharing what I know

Comment: #1) With my current knowledge, I see two options 1) 1 Amazon Account, which is used to setup a DEV box and creates users in that dev box that the developers can then log on to OR 2) _Each_ developer has their own amazon login and manages their own instance to develop and test. Eclipe IDE integration makes 2) a breeze

Comment: #2) This what I do. For security, I have a local in-house server that has the code repositories. I develop on my personal machine while managing the version between my dev machine and in-house repository. Amazon EC2 only comes into play when I deploy that code to my test or prod box in Amazon EC2. You may chose to host your code repository in an Amazon instance as well.